# Using "Until" with the Past continuous, Past simple and Past perfect

Tags: grammar

In English are we able to use "Until" with the Past continuous, Past simple and Past perfect tenses?

He was watching Television until his Mother got home.
He had watched Television until his Mother got home.
He watched Television until his Mother got home.

He was studying Spanish until dinner was ready.
He had studied Spanish until dinner was ready.
He studied Spanish until dinner was ready.

Comment: Yes, FalaGringo. Those sentences are all fine.